# How to save and load data in realm

Tags: android, json, realm

I have a json file and would load to realm file.  If I want to update the json file, e.g. notification, how I can do it through realm?

By default notification set to yes, want to update to no.  And when restart the file, notification will set to no.

My question is how to to save and load data in realm.

```
public class Setting extends RealmObject {

    @Required
    private Boolean Notification;
    private RealmList<Translation> Translations;

    public Boolean getNotification() {
        return Notification;
    }

    public void setNotification(Boolean notification) {
        Notification = notification;
    }

    public RealmList<Translation> getTranslations() {
        return Translations;
    }

    public void setTranslations(RealmList<Translation> translations) {
        Translations = translations;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you only need one `Setting` object to be stored in the Realm. So whenever you want to write/read it, always using `findFirst` to try to get the only `Setting` object like below:

```java
static Setting getSettingInstance(Realm realm) {
    Setting setting = realm.where(Setting.class).findFirst();
    if (setting == null) {
        // The object doesn't exist.
        realm.beginTransaction();
        setting = realm.createObject(Setting.class);
        setting.setNotification(true); // Make it default to true
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }
    return setting;
}
```

When you want to change the notification:

```java
Setting setting = getSettingInstance(realm);
realm.beginTransaction();
setting.setNotification(false);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

I am not quite sure what do you want to do with JSON, but you can have a look with Realm's JSON related functions like [this](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#createObjectFromJson-java.lang.Class-java.io.InputStream-).

About writing to Realm, see [doc](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#writes).